# How to treat and access the elements of an ArrayList of ArrayList of ArrayList of ArrayList

Tags: java, json, matrix, arraylist

I have a JSONObject that I pass to JSONArray and then I create an ArrayList of that JSONArray, but my problem is that that ArrayList that is generated from the JSONArray is an ArrayList of ArrayList of ArrayList of ArrayList.
I show it in this photo:

[image: Array of ArrayList of ArrayList of ArrayList]

I want to access that last area that is seen from the ArrayList to process this data, but this type of ArrayList from ArrayList from ArrayList from ArrayList I can't get to treat it, navigate it or access it.

My code is like this

```
     String PasamosJsonAstring="";
     JSONObject OtroObjeto = new clienteeeeeeee().getAllTypes();    
     PasamosJsonAstring=OtroObjeto.toString();
     System.out.println(OtroObjeto);

     JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
     json.put(OtroObjeto.get("result"));

     ArrayList<JSONArray> listado = new ArrayList<JSONArray>();
     listado.add(json);
     System.out.println(listado);
```

This code brings this out to me on the screen:

> 

```
[[[[[12,"01",1,"Fallo de corriente",0,1,"Bombeo Regatillo(Sax)"], 
  [12,"01",2,"Nivel máximo",0,0,"Bombeo Regatillo(Sax)"],[12,"01",3,"Nivel 
  mínimo",0,0,"Bombeo Regatillo(Sax)"],[12,"01",4,"Nivel 
  desborde",0,0,"Bombeo Regatillo(Sax)"],[12,"01",5,"Falta de 
  agua",0,0,"Bombeo Regatillo(Sax)"],[12,"01",6,"Exceso de 
  caudal",0,0,"Bombeo Regatillo(Sax)"],[12,"01",7,"Defecto de 
  caudal",0,0,"Bombeo Regatillo(Sax)"],[12,"01",8,"Defecto de tensión 
  L1",0,0,"Bombeo Regatillo(Sax)"],[12,"01",9,"Defecto de tensión 
  L2",0,0,"Bombeo Regatillo(Sax)"],[12,"01",10,"Defecto de tensión 
  L3",0,0,"Bombeo Regatillo(Sax)"],[12,"01",11,"Exceso de intensidad 
  L1",0,0,"Bombeo Regatillo(Sax)"],[12,"01",12,"Exceso de intensidad 
  L2",0,0,"Bombeo Regatillo(Sax)"],[12,"01",13,"Exceso de intensidad 
  L3",0,0,"Bombeo Regatillo(Sax)"],[12,"02",1,"Nivel mínimo 
  dep.",0,0,"Embalse Cabeza Pelada(Sax)"],[12,"02",2,"Nivel máximo 
  dep.",0,0,"Embalse Cabeza Pelada(Sax)"],[12,"02",3,"Defecto de 
  batería",0,0,"Embalse Cabeza Pelada(Sax)"]]]]]
```

I want to get it out like this

```
 12.0011.0Fallo de corriente0.01.0Bombeo Regatillo(Sax)

12.0012.0Nivel máximo0.00.0Bombeo Regatillo(Sax)

12.0013.0Nivel mínimo0.00.0Bombeo Regatillo(Sax)

12.0014.0Nivel desborde0.00.0Bombeo Regatillo(Sax)

12.0015.0Falta de agua0.00.0Bombeo Regatillo(Sax)

12.0016.0Exceso de caudal0.00.0Bombeo Regatillo(Sax)

12.0017.0Defecto de caudal0.00.0Bombeo Regatillo(Sax)

12.0018.0Defecto de tensión L10.00.0Bombeo Regatillo(Sax)

12.0019.0Defecto de tensión L20.00.0Bombeo Regatillo(Sax)

12.00110.0Defecto de tensión L30.00.0Bombeo Regatillo(Sax)

12.00111.0Exceso de intensidad L10.00.0Bombeo Regatillo(Sax)

12.00112.0Exceso de intensidad L20.00.0Bombeo Regatillo(Sax)

12.00113.0Exceso de intensidad L30.00.0Bombeo Regatillo(Sax)

12.0021.0Nivel mínimo dep.0.00.0Embalse Cabeza Pelada(Sax)

12.0022.0Nivel máximo dep.0.00.0Embalse Cabeza Pelada(Sax)

12.0023.0Defecto de batería0.00.0Embalse Cabeza Pelada(Sax)
```

To do this I need to go through the array array array array but I don't know how to access or convert it to a type to be able to treat it

I would like to understand this and some light on this.

Comment: Voting to close and downvote because no attempt and no details of the actual issue or representation of that in your specific code. Why cant you just do `foo.get(i).get(j).get(k)`? Or dont you have it as `List<List<List<Foo>>>`? How exactly are you representing that JSON data in code? And why dont you just map it to concrete Java classes, for example using GSON or Jackson.

Comment: @Zabuza Edit my question with my code and clearly expressing my doubt, sorry.